# Compose TopAppBar has no background color

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I want to add a `TopAppBar` to my Compose app, so I did the following:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            AlternoTubeTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    Scaffold(
                        topBar = {
                            TopAppBar(
                                title = {
                                    Text(
                                        stringResource(id = R.string.app_name),
                                        maxLines = 1,
                                        overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis
                                    )
                                },
                            )
                        },
                        content = { innerPadding ->
                            MyAppTheme(modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding))
                        }
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The issue is, when I run the app, there is no color to my `TopAppBar`:

[image]

Whereas on the preview images, the app bar does have colors:

[image]

What can I try next to get the right colors?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

With **M3** the default value of the background color in the `TopAppBar` is defined in the **`TopAppBarDefaults.smallTopAppBarColors()`** with the **`containerColor`** attribute. The default value is the `surface` color defined in your theme.

Check your theme or you can override it using something like:

```
TopAppBar(
    title = {
        Text(
            stringResource(id = R.string.app_name),
            maxLines = 1,
            overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis
        )
    },
    colors = TopAppBarDefaults.smallTopAppBarColors(containerColor = Yellow)
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, how do I change my colors so that they match those in the image?

Comment: Why is my surface color not the one that was in the example? I did a normal project setup, do you know any copy paste I could do so I can get those configurations?

Comment: You can start from the doc: https://m3.material.io/styles/color/the-color-system/tokens#7fd4440e-986d-443f-8b3a-4933bff16646
The default value defined in the `surface` color is currently =  `Neutral99 = Color(red = 255, green = 251, blue = 254)`

Comment: Thanks for the link, I think it's possibly an internal bug -- that should _not_ be the default `surface` color.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Can I add a custom image in M3 TopAppBar? I show `background` argument is removed in M3. I tried using `Modifier.paint()` but it's not reflecting TopAppBar. Any suggestion?

Comment: you are hard coding containerColor what if I want to change it according to the dark mode?

Answer (score 19):

### Update July 23  M3 `TopAppBarDefaults.smallTopAppBarColors()` is deprecated

Now the color need to assign as `TopAppBarDefaults.topAppBarColors` making accepted answer deprecated.

Here is snippet of composable function for creating top App bar with customc colors for its background, Title, Navigation icon & Action icons adopting to theme colors instead of harcoded colors:

```
@Composable
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
private fun ToolBar(
    title: String,
    onNavigationClick: () -> Unit,
    onSettingClick: () -> Unit
) {

    TopAppBar(
        // Customize Colors here
        colors = TopAppBarDefaults.topAppBarColors(
            containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
            titleContentColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimary,
            navigationIconContentColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimary,
            actionIconContentColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSecondary
        ),
        navigationIcon = {
            IconButton(onClick = onNavigationClick) {
                Icon(
                    imageVector = Icons.Filled.Menu,
                    contentDescription = "Navigation icon"
                )
            }
        },
        title = { Text(title) },
        actions = {
            IconButton(onClick = onSettingClick) {
                Icon(
                    Icons.Filled.Settings,
                    contentDescription = "Settings"
                )
            }
        })
}
```

usage:

```
Scaffold(
    topBar = {
        ToolBar( "Home Page", { /** handle Navigation Click */}) {
           /** handle Action Click*/
        }
    },
```

Light Mode

[image]

Dark Mode

[image]

Comment: Thank you for providing this answer. You already helped me within 7 hours ^_^

Comment: i have used `containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surface` and I have also defined `surface` color in `Theme.kt` class but it is not picking that `surface` color for its background.